# Numeric Range Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, nested-sets, modified-preorder-tree-t

I have an set numeric ranges that I would like to optimize.

Here's a simple example of initial values:

```
Start    End
9        12
1        2
60       88
10       11
79       80
```

What I'd expect as output after optimization:

```
Start    End
1        2
9        12
60       88
```

These are the `left` and `right` values from Modified Preorder Tree Traversal (Nested Set) data stored in a MySQL database.  I use them to exclude inactive branches from the result, and am not currently optimizing the ranges at all. I thought I might get a performance gain from optimizing the ranges before use.

---

**MORE INFO**

The values are passed into a query for exclusion of the inactive branches in the tree using a `NOT BETWEEN` clause.  I thought that I could optimize the performance of that query by using a minimal set of ranges.

Comment: So you want to collapse a set of ranges into the minimal set of ranges.

Comment: You are selecting the top level in the nested set. That can be done in SQL.

Comment: @Unreason - Can you elaborate with a query example?

Comment: no time now, take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an SQL that will return what you want

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE sample (Start INT, End INT);

mysql> INSERT sample VALUES (9,12),(1,2),(60,88),(10,11),(79,80);

mysql> SELECT * 
    -> FROM sample s 
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    ->                   FROM sample 
    ->                   WHERE s.Start > Start AND s.Start < End);
+-------+------+
| Start | End  |
+-------+------+
|     9 |   12 |
|     1 |    2 |
|    60 |   88 |
+-------+------+
```

You can, of course, create VIEW, move the data to another table or delete rows using the above SQL.

NOTE: I am not really sure why are you doing this 'optimization'.

EDIT:
The query can be rewritten as

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM sample s LEFT JOIN 
     sample s2 ON s.Start > s2.Start AND s.Start < s2.End 
WHERE s2.start IS NULL;
```

Which will create different execution plan (2xsimple select vs primary/dependent subquery for EXISTS), so performance might be different. Both queries will use an index on (Start, End) if it exists.

Comment: This works great! I am now noticing that I have adjacent nodes that I'd like to combine as well. `1,2` and `3,4` would become `1,4`.

Comment: @Sonny, ok - that is a different problem and for that problem other proposed solutions are good algorithms. However, I am a bit puzzled as to what is your purpose? Optimizing nested sets in general use scenario is NOT necessary - it is already an optimized data structure made to make use of DB indexes for otherwise recursive queries.

Comment: I think I am going to create a new post when I get the chance.  I might be approaching it wrong, or my current solution might be optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a sorted list. Mark which elements in the sorted list represent range starts and which are range ends. Sort the list based on value first; however, make sure that range starts come before range ends. (This will probably involve a structure of some sort that can be sorted on a given key. I don't know the details in php.)

Now, traverse the list from start to end. Keep a counter, `c`. When you pass a range start, increment `c`. When you pass a range end, decrement `c`.

When `c` goes from 0 to 1, that's the start of a range in the final set. When `c` goes from 1 to 0, that's the end of a range.

**EDIT::** If you already have the ranges in a database table somewhere, you can probably structure an SQL query to do the first step above (again, making sure that range start-points are returned before range end-points).

Comment: It's also enough to put the range starts into one list and the range ends to *another* list; then you iterate them both, having two pointers and advancing the one that points to a lower number. In this way the question about relative order of range starts and ends goes away also, and it should be even easier to do in SQL (make two queries, one for range starts, one for range ends, and just sort them in the SQL query itself)

Comment: This approach works with a general problem of finding union of ranges. You should note that OP asks specifically for ranges that come from 'nested sets' - where ranges are either proper subsets or have no intersection (hence nested).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
// I picked this format because it's convenient for the solution
// and because it's very natural for a human to read/write
$ranges = array(
  9    =>    12,
  1    =>    2,
  60   =>    81,
  10   =>    11,
  79   =>    88);

ksort($ranges);
$count = count($ranges);
$prev = null; // holds the previous start-end pair

foreach($ranges as $start => $end) {
    // If this range overlaps or is adjacent to the previous one
    if ($prev !== null && $start <= $prev[1] + 1) {
        // Update the previous one (both in $prev and in $ranges)
        // to the union of its previous value and the current range
        $ranges[$prev[0]] = $prev[1] = max($end, $prev[1]);

        // Mark the current range as "deleted"
        $ranges[$start] = null;
        continue;
    }

    $prev = array($start, $end);
}

// Filter all "deleted" ranges out
$ranges = array_filter($ranges);
```

Limitations/notes:

1. The range boundaries have to be small enough to fit into an `int`.
2. This example will incorrectly remove any range from the final result if the ending boundary is `0`. If your data can legitimately contain such a range, provide an appropriate callback to `array_filter`: `function($item) { return $item === null; }`.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/gZDqB)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ranges = array(
  array(9, 12),
  array(1, 2),
  array(60, 81),
  array(10, 11),
  array(79, 88),
  );

function optimizeRangeArray($r) {
  $flagarr = array();
  foreach ($r as $range => $bounds) {
    $flagarr = array_pad($flagarr, $bounds[1], false);
    for ($i = $bounds[0]-1; $i < $bounds[1]; $i++) $flagarr[$i] = true;
    }
  $res = array(); $min = 0; $max = 0; $laststate = false;
  $ctr = 0;
  foreach ($flagarr as $state) {
    if ($state != $laststate) {
      if ($state) $min = $ctr + 1;
      else {
        $max = $ctr;
        $res[] = array($min, $max);
        }
      $laststate = $state;
      }
    $ctr++;
    }
  $max = $ctr;
  $res[] = array($min, $max);
  return($res);
  }

print_r(optimizeRangeArray($ranges));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 60
            [1] => 88
        )

)
```

*Note: This doesn't work for negative integers!*

Or use it like this

```
$rres = optimizeRangeArray($ranges);

$out = "<pre>Start    End<br />";
foreach($rres as $range=>$bounds) {
  $out .= str_pad($bounds[0], 9, ' ') . str_pad($bounds[1], 9, ' ') . "<br />";
  }
$out .= "</pre>";
echo $out;
```

To get this in your browser

```
Start    End
1        2
9        12
60       88
```